# Is base64 encoding/decoding available through the NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to do some relatively heavy computing in native code, but I don't know if I will have to implement the functionality myself or if  it is already available through the NDK.

What I need in native code is Base64 encoding and decoding. So I ask of you, is this possible? Is Base64 endocing/decoding exposed via the NDK? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is pretty trivial and there are a lot of implementations. For example: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

Comment: Thanks for that link... it will help... :)